# Is playing Vimeo video can affect Vimeo rate limit?

Tags: ios, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-ios

I am getting rate "limit exceed error".
I know about Vimeo rate limit conditions and I am caching api calls response for reducing Vimeo hits.

I am not sure that playing a Vimeo video can affect rate limit or not.

I am using Vimeo video external player url for playing video in my iOS project.

```
Example: https://player.vimeo.com/external/176590201.sd.mp4?s=......&profile_id=...&oauth2_token_id=...
```

[Video Link](https://player.vimeo.com/external/176590201.sd.mp4?s=c557450c4dea6d03d61029fe4bce98d49478834e&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=418141207)

Is it possible that playing a Vimeo video consider as a api call to Vimeo server and affect rate limit?

Any suggestion or link will much appreciated.

Comment: I got a reply from Vimeo developer support that playing Vimeo video directly from external player url does not count as Api count. Only request to "api.vimeo.com" will considered as a api hit and affect rate limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, playing a Vimeo video (either using the external player link you mentioned or using the Vimeo iframe player) will not increment the API rate limit.

Only requests to https://api.vimeo.com where a response body is expected should increment the rate limit.

For example, `GET https://api.vimeo.com/me` (reading the metadata for your Vimeo account) *will* increment the rate limit because a response body is returned.

However `DELETE https://api.vimeo.com/[complete_uri]` ([Completing a streaming upload](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#complete-the-upload)) *will not* increment the rate limit because only a header is returned.

Comment: Is this still the case? Is it correct that playing an embedded video using the Player SDK does not incur the rate limit?  (Player SDK: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/basics)

Comment: @9gt53wS Yes, that information is still accurate. The Player SDK is completely separate from the Vimeo API.